# Rally - Data Context and InlineFilter issue in a RallyGridBoard

Tags: rally

**Objective :** 
Trying to build a Rally App to populate "PortFolioItem/features" based upon a Project value selected from a userSearchCombo box.

**Methodology:**
 1. Creating a UserSearchComboBox based upon the 'Project' model.
 2. Depending upon the value selected from the combo box,Creating a TreeStore based on the model 'PortfolioItem/Feature'.

The context scoped for the tree Store is based on the value selected from the Project Search Combo Box

```
 app.portfoliotreeStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
                    models: modelNames,
                    autoLoad: true,
                    enableHierarchy: true,
                    limit: 'Infinity',
                    remoteSort: true,
                    //        sorters: app.appSorters,
                    //fetch: ['Name', 'FormattedID', 'ScheduleState', 'PlanEstimate', 'Owner', 'Project'],
                    //filters: filters,
                    // filters: this.getQueryFilter(),
                    context: {
                        project: app.selProjectRef,
                        projectScopeDown: true
                    }

                }).then({
                    success: this._addGridboard,
                    failure: this.showErrorNotification,
                    scope: this
                });
```

3. In the Add grid Board Method ,created a gridBoard with some plugins

   ```
    _addGridboard: function(store) {
               console.log("Entering _addGridBoard", store);
               app.portfoliotreeStore = store;
               var modelNames = ['portfolioitem/PPMFeature']
               var filters = app.getStoreFilters(app.selProjectName);

               console.log("the Grid", app.down('#gridContainer'));
               if (app.down('#gridContainer')) {
                   app.down('#gridContainer').remove('gridBoard');
               }
               //this.gridBoardConfig = app._getGridBoardConfig(store);

               var dataContext = app.getContext().getDataContext();
               console.log("DATA CONTEXT ::::", dataContext);

               gridStateString = this.statePrefix + "-treegrid";
               gridStateId = this.getContext().getScopedStateId(gridStateString);
               app.down('#gridContainer').add({
                   xtype: 'rallygridboard',
                   itemId: 'gridBoard',
                   //  context: this.getContext(),
                   modelNames: ['portfolioitem/PPMFeature'],
                   toggleState: 'grid',
                   plugins: [

                       'rallygridboardaddnew', {
                           ptype: 'rallygridboardinlinefiltercontrol',
                           inlineFilterButtonConfig: {
                               //stateful: true,
                               //stateId: this.getContext().getScopedStateId('filters-1'),
                               //collapsed: true,
                               context: this.getContext(),
                               modelNames: ['portfolioitem/PPMFeature'],
                               inlineFilterPanelConfig: {

                                   collapsed: true,
                                   quickFilterPanelConfig: {
                                       whiteListFields: [
                                           'Tags',
                                           'Milestones'
                                       ],
                                       defaultFields: [
                                           'ArtifactSearch',
                                           'Owner',
                                           'ModelType',
                                           'Milestones'
                                       ]
                                   }

                               }
                           }
                       },

                       {
                           ptype: 'rallygridboardfieldpicker',
                           headerPosition: 'left',
                           modelNames: this._getModelNames()
                               //stateful: true,
                               //stateId: this.getContext().getScopedStateId('columns-example')
                       }

                   ],
                   stateful: true,
                   listeners: {
                       'staterestore': {
                           fn: this._onGridStateRestore,
                           single: true
                       },
                       'load': {
                           fn: this._onGridload,
                           single: true
                       },
                       scope: this



                   },

                   gridConfig: {
                       store: store,
                       storeConfig: {
                           filters: this.getQueryFilter()
                       },

                       columnCfgs: [
                           'Name',
                           'Project',
                           'ScheduleState',
                           'Owner',
                           'PlanEstimate'
                       ]

                       // derivedColumns: this.getDerivedColumns()
                   },

                   /*
                   gridConfig: {
                       store: store,
                       storeConfig: {
                           filters: this.getQueryFilter()
                       },

                       columnCfgs: [
                           'Name',
                           'Project',
                           'ScheduleState',
                           'Owner',
                           'PlanEstimate'
                       ],

                       // derivedColumns: this.getDerivedColumns()
                   },
                   */
                   height: this.getHeight()
               });

           },
   ```

   4. Please Note the following

      - Not passing any context to the grid component - Reason:: if i pass 
        "this.getContext" to the Grid, duplicates records are initially loaded into 
        the grid , once i click on any header to sort the grid,the duplicates disappear.

**Issue: catch 22 Situation**
The only way for me to get rid of the duplicates is to not pass the context to the GridBoard, However this impacts my Plugin - "rallygridboardinlinefiltercontrol"

if i scroll over my InlinefilterButton , it throws this error

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'collapsed' of undefined
at constructor._onBeforeShowToolTip (VM556 sdk.js:100)
at constructor.fire (VM556 sdk.js:5)
at constructor.continueFireEvent (VM556 sdk.js:6)
at constructor.fireEventArgs (VM556 sdk.js:6)
at constructor.prototype.fireEventArgs (VM556 sdk.js:18)
at constructor.fireEvent (VM556 sdk.js:6)
at constructor.show (VM556 sdk.js:15)
at constructor.callParent (VM556 sdk.js:2)
at constructor.show (VM556 sdk.js:25)
at constructor.showFromDelay (VM556 sdk.js:25)
```

And when i Click on it , it Throws this Error

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleCollapse' of undefined
at constructor._toggleFilterPanel (VM556 sdk.js:100)
at call (VM556 sdk.js:5)
```

It does not impact my other filters

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I finally found the Issue ... It appears , i need to pass the Context to the grid , but i also need to switch the autoload on the TreeGrid to false , this is because the plugin owns the responsibility of loading the store .... YAY !! Eureka Eureaka I got this ... Can any one sugest any good book on Rally..